# JQuery Selector not accepting string with escaped characters as argument

Tags: jquery

In my console I'm performing:

```
thing = '#'+id.replace(new RegExp(" ", "g"), "_").replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;
        <=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, "\\\\$&")
```

and being told that these are the contents of `thing`:

```
"#Accounting\\/Payroll"
```

and that

```
>typeof(thing)
>"string"
```

When I perform:

```
$(thing)
```

I get

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Accounting\\/Payroll
    at Function.ga.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ga.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ga.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r (jquery.min.js:2)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

But when I perform

```
$("#Accounting\\/Payroll")
```

I get

```
    [div#Accounting/Payroll.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3.department, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
```

So what am I doing wrong with my first selector?

## EDIT: Got It

I think I get it now. The escape is evaluated when the string is stored. So when I'm typing `"#Accounting\\/Payroll"`literally into the selector, jquery is using the stored string `"#Accounting\/Payroll"` as its selector. My first usage doesn't work because it's using the stored string `"#Accounting\\/Payroll"` as its selector. Thanks adeneo.

Comment: Try removing a slash from the first one `"\\\$&"`, or even better stop using slashes in your ID's

Comment: Of course I can remove slashes. That's not my question. I don't want to remove slashes from my ID's if I can help it.

Comment: Removing one of the `\` from `"\\\$&"` works. Why is it okay to have two slashes when I type the id string explicitly with 2 escape slashes but it's not ok when I use the selector like `$(thing)` any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking why it works? Because when literally typing `"\\"` it's different from creating a string with `"\\"` , when you type it literally the first escape escapes the second escape etc.

Comment: I had no idea that typing it literally would result in different behavior. I thought that typing out a string into a selector with escaped characters was exactly the same as using a stored string in a selector with escaped characters. Thanks.

Comment: In some ways it is, but when you literally type escape characters the first one is escaped by the parser, so you need two too keep one for jQuery etc. When you programatically create a string, both escape characters are passed to jQuery instead.